# How to fix this php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I printed out what was supposed to be a multidimensional array in php but saw this instead. It was throwing errors when I tried to access `$array['order_item']['sku']`. How do I convert this to a proper multidimensional array?

```
Array
(
[order_item] => [{"name":"Product","sku":"14b6c7e2f838fd356","description":"Product Standard Download","price":"76.0000","qty":1,"tax":0}]
[customer] => {"first_name":"Johny","last_name":"Smith","email":"johnyzc@gmail.com"}
)
```

Comment: Loop over the array and call [json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode) on each value.

Comment: Also, the order_item key would be an array of arrays. So the first sku would be `$array['order_item'][0]['sku']`. Appears that this structure would allow multiple "order items" per "customer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
$array = array(
    'order_item' => '[{"name":"Product","sku":"14b6c7e2f838fd356","description":"Product Standard Download","price":"76.0000","qty":1,"tax":0}]',
    'customer' => '{"first_name":"Johny","last_name":"Smith","email":"johnyzc@gmail.com"}'
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = json_decode($array[$key], TRUE);
}
echo $array['order_item'][0]['sku'];
```

this will give: **14b6c7e2f838fd356**

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to create multidimensional arrays in php is as follows:

$array['order_item']['name'] = "Product";

And so on